# Custom Attribute is not saving data in database

Tags: magento2, database, product-attribute, installdata

I'm trying to add custom text box named cashback in Magento 2 product add/edit page. I added the text box programmatically. But my below code doesn't add column in the table also not saving the value. I'm a beginner so I can't understand Magento 2 structure. I need clarification about which table does it stores and need to store data given in admin panel.

```
<?php

namespace Rk\Wallet\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    )
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
          "cashback",
          [
          'group' => "",
          'label' => "Cashback",
          'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
          'default' => '1',
          'note' => '',
          'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
          'visible' => true,
          'required' => false,
          'user_defined' => true,
          'searchable' => true,
          'filterable' => true,
          'comparable' => false,
          'visible_on_front' => true,
          'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
          'unique' => false,
          "frontend_class" => "cashbackclass",
          "used_in_product_listing" => true,
          "type"                    => "int",
          "input" => "text",
          "type" => "int",
          "source" => "Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\TimeSetup",
          'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend'
          ]
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @ramesh KR, download this module and Let's try this in default magento2. https://mage2gen.com/load/7af32833-a2a2-405e-9e21-51510e617407?main_version=2

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 stores setup data/schema versions in setup_module table. I think that first what you have done was to run setup:upgrade after you added module and according version was set in table.

InstallData/Schema scripts are run only when there is no version stored in db, so at the first run of setup upgrade. If my assumption is correct then either remove relevant entry in setup_module table or put your script into UpgradeData and update module's version in etc/module.xml to higher.

Check other UpgradeData scripts to see how you can compare versions.

Comment: thanks @Bartosh but also after upgrading setup and module version it remains the same.

Comment: Thanks @Bartosh after removing module record the table value saved.

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your script. please try this.

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'cashback', [
            'group' => 'Product Details',
            'type' => 'text',
            'sort_order' => 102,
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'CashBack',
            'input' => 'textarea',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => true,
            'filterable' => true,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable'
        ]);
    }
```

**Note:** Remove the entry of your module from `setup_module` table. Also check the attribute named **cashback** in eav_attribute table. If you find one, remove that as well.

Comment: thanks @Sachin Agarwal above code not added column in eav_attribute table. I need your help. I added new textbox named 'cashback' in adminpanel. Now I need to add the entered value in the text box  to the new column in catalog_product_entity table. Pls help me.

Comment: @RameshKR You don't need to add a new column in the catalog_product_entity table. The eav_attribute table must a record for this cashback record. So catalog_product_entity_varchar table will store the value of this cashback attribute with the attribute_id which you ca find in the eav_attribute table.

Comment: also no column like cashback found in eav_attribute tabel

Comment: @RameshKR FYI: eav_attribute doesn't have a new column. it has new record (Row) for you attribute.

Comment: Thanks Sachin Agarwal. Cashback attribute code is updated in db. I have a text box in magento product edit page. I need to save the value given in the text box into the db. After entering data into text box and giving save it's not saving the value. For example if I give 10 in the text box in have to save. This is my logic. Pls help I searched lot of tutorials but I'm a beginner.

Comment: @RameshKR FIrst get the entity_id of the product you saved last with the cashback value. then get the attribute_id  of the cashback attribute from the eav_attribute table.. Then try to find the record by searching these two values in the catalog_product_entity_text or catalog_product_entity_varchar tables.

Comment: Thanks a lot @sachin. I have entity_id and attribute_id matches in catalog_product_entity_varchar table. But the value saved is 'one', I saved the value 20 on admin dashboard. After clicking on save button on admin product edit page I reloads but the value on text box is empty.

Comment: Your attribute value would be in the catalog_product_entity_text table.. please do not look into the varchar table.. Its working good at my end.. when I save product with value 20 it shows me 20 as it should be.

Comment: Searching for attribute id in catalog_product_entity_text there is no results found

Comment: You must be doing something wrong man!!!  Please try to everything again step by step. Its quite simple.

Comment: I'll do it sure

Comment: Thanks a lot Sachin. It working perfectly. you saved my day. And finally I need a small help. I need to add this cashback value to customer entity if the transaction is successful. I hope you'll help me.